# Get clicks statistics in bitly with adding + sign at the and of shortened link doesn't work now

Tags: bit.ly

I'm trying to get clicks statistics from bitly with adding + sign at the end of the shortened link, but it doesn't work now

[image: This is a screenshot of statistics page]

anyone can help?

this is my shortened link: bit.ly/2Sb5MBg

Comment: What version of bit.ly are you using?

Comment: i just use free version

Answer (score 0):

Bit.ly have changed things not long ago. now to be able to get the data for he amount of clicks you have to log in to do so. So the usual + at the end no longer works when you are not logged in.